# WebSphere Portal Spring Security

Tags: spring-security, websphere-portal

I am doing some research to determine if Spring Security can be used with WebSphere Portal 7.x.  I have reviewed the Spring Security documentation and did not see anything that leads me to believe that it can not be integrated into our application.

We will be using WebSphere Portal Security for Authentication (LDAP - to verify the identity of the user and what Portal/Portlets they can see and use) and Spring Security for authorization of what part of the portlet they have access to.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this? I have the same question.

Comment: No one has posted a response.  Based on my research I could not find anyone things saying that it can not be used.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm...  the last time I looked into that, there was no direct support for the portal API in Spring Security 3.0.  As of Spring Security 3, the portal support was moved out of the main distribution into a Spring Security Extendsions project.  The last official portal support was in version 2.0.6.

The deal is that the older portal support was not updated to support JSR 286.  I wrote my own to provide this functionality that allows me to use Spring Security 3.x.  Once I finish testing, I'll see if I can contribute it back.

Regards,

Joshua

Comment: Did you effectively get it working to support JSR 286?